# how can i solve the missing winload.efi file in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

when i start my pc which is having windows 8 OS. Iam getting the error like this
Your PC needs to be repaired
The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
File: \Windows\system32\winload.efi
Error code: 0xc0000225
You'll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your system administrator or PC manufacturer
Press Enter to try again
Press F8 for Startup Settings

pls try to provide solution to get rid of this problem

Comment: So you don't have the installation media?